# AppendText only works with large strings

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, append, richtextbox

so I'm trying to load a file into a richtextbox, but I'm having some problems. No matter what method I used, binaryreader, filestream, streamreader I always encountered a problem with loading a file into a richtextbox in chunks. (I can't use LoadFile as it doesn't let me specify encoding). It seems that if the buffer size is too small, smaller than 3MB, AppendText sometimes adds a few extra empty lines. The file itself doesn't lose any data, there are just a few extra lines appended to it. Here is the code I'm using:

```
richTextBox.Clear();
            progressBar.Value = 0;
            const int bufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 3; //I've tried smaller buffers but they ALL seem to append a few extra lines (empty lines)

            using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                while (streamReader.Peek() != -1)
                {
                    char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
                    await streamReader.ReadBlockAsync(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    richTextBox.AppendText(new string(buffer));
                    progressBar.Value = (int)(((double)streamReader.BaseStream.Position) / streamReader.BaseStream.Length * 100);
                }
            }
```

This code seems to work, but I'm paranoid that it might still append extra lines at times depending on the circumstances. Does anybody know why this could be occurring?

*Extra Questions
Is using StreamReader slower than FileStream or binaryreader?
Should I use readblock or read?

Comment: in regards to extra question: unless you seriously need the performance (in which case you are probably using the wrong language), I would not worry _too much_ about performance

Comment: Maybe the source file has these extra lines.

Comment: No, I copied the text from the richtextbox into notepad++, and saved the file, and then performed a sha256 hash on them. They were different.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way you can use; it gives same format as in file:

```cs
OpenFileDialog fil = new OpenFileDialog();
if (fil.ShowDialog()== DialogResult.OK)
{
    richTextBox1.Clear();
    richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllText(fil.FileName);                
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to load the file in chunks.